# Problem with P&T Field Pack variables inside Safecracker

Tags: safecracker, field-pack

Using EE v2.6.1 Safecracker and P&T Field Pack v2.0.2

P&T Field Pack dropdown variables with value or label tags don't work inside  Safecracker form tag pairs.

This code:

```
{exp:safecracker channel="channel_name" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    1: {field:my_field}
    2: {my_field}
    3: {my_field:value}
    4: {my_field:label}
{/exp:safecracker}
```

Returns:

1: a select input conatining all options of my_field with current value selected

2: field's current value

3: NOTHING

4: NOTHING

It used to be working on EE v2.5.5

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Would using {field:my_field_name} work in your case?

Comment: That works but I need it to be customized.

Comment: Have a look over the question again, I've edited it to be more specific.